# is it possible to position letter x in center of console, drop at 100pixels/second, and raise 50pixels on click?

Tags: c++, console, console-application, motion

This is essentially the rudimentary version of the motion in jetpack joyride but instead of the joyrider falling at 100pixels per second, it would be the letter "x" falling at 100pixels per second from the exact middle of the console and a click event would cause it to rise at 50 pixels per second. I am really new at this so if this isn't possible in c++ please let me know. Thanks.

EDIT: I am using sublime text to write my code, and the MinGW compiler.

Comment: If you want to make a game, use a game library.

Answer (score 2):

No. Characters on the console can only appear on the character grid; you can't move them around to pixel-exact coordinates.

For what it's worth, this would be trivial to do in a web browser.

Comment: Could you kindly provide me a direction or term I guess to look for so I can position an object on screen and have it move with the motion and click event I described above?

Comment: @VictorCharlesRoskowski Learn some HTML, CSS and Javascript. That should teach you the basics needed for doing this in a browser.